# ZF2 Modules & external dependencies

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm not clear on what the best practice is for including external libraries in a custom module that I plan on distributing.

Normally I'd place the external library under the application's vendor directory. But I want to ensure that all dependencies are met when I distribute my custom module (i.e. I don't want to force people to manually download the dependency into their app's vendor directory).

Is the correct practice to include a vendor directory under the module directory as per the the following?

```
/application_dir
     /vendor
     /module
          /my_module
              /vendor
```

Comment: Use composer for dependencies. This is common best practice nowadays and pretty much the only thing accepted by the community. If you deliver dependencies with your code and there's an update, what then?

Comment: Sam said everything. Use composer to handle your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use composer, you can find documentation here:

[Composer Documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

Basically you would modify the file composer.json in the root of your application and add your dependencies in the require section:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/common": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zendpdf": "2.*",
        "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.*",
        "thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr": ">= 0.1.2",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master"
        // add your requirements here**
    }
}
```

if the dependancy is on a private github repository, you can add it like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Don't forget to do composer.phar update after your done adding them.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but what do you do if the external library is not hosted in a repository, but you simply download it as a zip file from a web page? Do you just include it under the source tree of your own project?